# Using QjsonDocument to parse api data in QT

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing, qjson

I have the below `JSON` which I am attempting to parse out.

```
{
    "btc_usd": {
        "high": 245.304,
        "low": 240.10001,
        "avg": 242.702005,
        "vol": 1406884.29972,
        "vol_cur": 5776.14075,
        "last": 242.9,
        "buy": 243.022,
        "sell": 242.9,
        "updated": 1435270412
    },
    "btc_rur": {
        "high": 13150,
        "low": 12912,
        "avg": 13031,
        "vol": 5397157.58979,
        "vol_cur": 413.89807,
        "last": 13139,
        "buy": 13139,
        "sell": 13071.00001,
        "updated": 1435270412
    }
}
```

This is how it comes formatted from the api in question.

However using the below example, I can not manage to pull out any of the data from the above json. I have attempted several ways to pull this data but have had no luck thus far.

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(reply->readAll());
QString rootObj = doc.object().value("").toString();
qDebug() << "results.count:" << rootObj.count();
```

Comment: It isn't binary.  It is human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to using:

[QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll())](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) instead of fromBinary and you should be good to go.

If you are still having trouble after that, pass in the optional `QJsonParseError` parameter into the static function and see what it is complaining about.

Hope that helps.